# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ status: typeof xyz; }

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript.

This is what I am doing.

```
//importing a class
import { ApiStatus } from "./src/api/ApiStatus";

const routes = {
  status: ApiStatus,
}

for (let route in routes) {
  if (routes.hasOwnProperty(route)) {
    const ApiClass = routes[route];
    const app = new ApiClass(context);
    console.notice(`Creating Api for ${route}`);
    exports[route] = app.handler; // Create api
  }
}
```

At this line

```
const ApiClass = routes[route];
```

it is throwing an error saying

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because the expression of type
>   'string' can't be used to index type '{ status: typeof ApiStatus; }'. 
>   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type
>   '{ status: typeof ApiStatus; }'

I am unable to comprehend this error, Can anyone explain to me what I could be doing wrong here? or the error?

Comment: can u share the code of ApiClass?

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell typescript how it can access the index type you have

```
interface IRoutes {
    [index: string]: any;
    status: ApiStatus;
    ...
}
const routes: IRoutes = {
   status: ApiStatus,
}
```

Comment: Yes it will suppress the error,  but I strongly discourage doing this, you are basically 'turning off typescript' by using `any`.

Comment: @amik I agree, having a BaseClass or BaseInterface is better than any, but in my solution you don't loose the typings when accessing `routes.status`! typescript knows its `ApiStatus`

Comment: Yes but you lose the typing when you access `routes[route]` since typescript has no runtime information that `route` is `'status'` there, so basically always in the above example.

Comment: @amik [of course it does](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECCAOBLAygFzKgrjA3tAvgFCGIB2qApgE4BmYwF0AkgEoD2mluh0v0A2mQAmFAB4AuaBFRUyAcwC6ksKQCeAbh59pGbJIQp0WCJr7QAdJcJFgbUtOhUOXSa2cUYAXmg4tUo3pwSGi6EAA01sSEtvao0AC2quycjN4A5DrGaZrRdg4A7gAWGEwQTHHeTikQ-InJlAo5QA)

Comment: [it does not](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECCAOBLAygFzKgrjA3tAvgFCGIB2qApgE4BmYwF0AkgEoD2mluh0v0A2mQAmFAB4AuaBFRUyAcwC6ksKQCeAbh59pGbJIQp0WCJr7QAdJcJFgbUtOhUOXSa2cUYAXmg4tUo3pwSGi6EAA01sSEtvao0AC2quycFJLSsqRy0N4A5DrGOZrRdg4A7gAWGEwQTHHeTikQ-InJlApFQA).  In your example, `myRoute` is of type `'status'`, not `string`, that is why your `whatIsIt` works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you iterate keys using `for (let route in routes)`, typescript infers type of `route` to be a `string`, but `routes` object is declared to have only `status` key and not any other. Therefore typescript is unable to determine what type is hidden behind `routes[route]`.

Possible solutions:

1. declare some interface e.g. `ApiInterface` to which all fields in `routes` conform and use:

```
const routes: {[key: string]: ApiInterface} = {
  status: ApiStatus
}
```

(supposing that `ApiStatus` and all future fields implement `ApiInterface`).

2. Do not use for..in (which is anyway not recommended in ES6+) and use a loop like this, which won't have any type issues:

```
Object.entries(routes).forEach(([route, ApiClass])
  const app = new ApiClass(context);
  console.notice(`Creating Api for ${route}`);
  exports[route] = app.handler; // Create api
}
```